# what does "/A" on the command - start "" /max "C:\Program Files Xxxxx.exe" /A "pagemode=FullScreen" "yourfile direction and name.pdf"

Tags: windows, command

I tried to open a pdf file on full screen using command lines, and I've sucessfully found this command :

`start "" /max "C:\Program Files Xxxxx.exe" /A "pagemode=FullScreen" "yourfile direction and name.pdf"`

on this topic :
https://superuser.com/questions/433293/how-to-open-a-pdf-in-full-screen-mode-by-command-line

My question is: what does the "/A" mean? Is that specific to start command ? I don't find any references about "/A" on the start command documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start

Thanks

Comment: Run utility help: `start /?`. `START ...   [command/program] [parameters]`. All words after exe-file call are executable `parameters`. So read `Xxxxx.exe` manual to get `/A` parameter meaning

Comment: Indeed, /A seem to be a parameter from acrord32.exe, but I can't see any documentation about it, only a lot of examples. 
There are some parameters which are formally defined (/n /s /o /h /p /t) : https://newbedev.com/adobe-reader-command-line-reference
Then /A seem to be used to set specific variables, but I can't manage to find the formal definition of /A parameter, neither than the list of variables that /A can specify… anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of a pdf /A is a common Adobe Acrobat switch to indicate /Actions

Thus for AcroRd32.exe/Acrobat.exe it can be used as an inline command line switch.

Some other Acrobat competitors may also accept some (probably only a sub set) of those directives! hence some confusion as to which to use across applications.

For your example, it would not work in PDF-xchange as the allowable ones are

> pagemode=<bookmarks|thumbs|none> – displays bookmarks or thumbnails.

> The default setting is none.

Other  apps use different means to switch behaviour e.g.

SumatraPDF.exe -FullScreen "yourfile directory and name.pdf"

Some of those same directives can be used at the end of a URL pointing to the PDF and should be used appended to the filename via #.

If the default PDF handler accepts them then

```
"file:///path/doc.pdf#page=2&view=Fit"
```

would be the equivalent of /A "page=2&view=Fit" "file:///path/doc.pdf"

see https://www.evermap.com/AutoBookmark/Manual/OpenParameters.htm

For a command to open msedge fullscreen with a file try

```
start "" msedge.exe --no-first-run --kiosk --new-window --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen "file:///C:\path with a space\mydemo.pdf#page=2"
```

then work from there.